# Need to align 4 divs and have them centered on page

Tags: html

So here is a picture of what I currently have [image]

My problem with this is everything is aligned to the left and I need it centered. I have tried to wrap them all in a single div and center that but it still doesn't work.  What is the simplest and cleanest way to center this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a wrapper `div` around the whole thing with a style like this:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 200px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

[**Live demo here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/DLeTP/)

Comment: thanks that did it I had to adjust the width to a larger size but it centered it thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap all the divs in one main div

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="top"></div>
   <div id="left"></div>
   <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

'#container {margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }'

That will place it in the center no matter how the screen is adjusted, add top and bottom to position where you want.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work, it's still aligned to the left